# Microsoft's high compression rate in their installation files

Tags: compression, installation-package

I was trying to understand what is in a .NET installation package, so I did unpack it with the /x option. At this point from a 70 Mbyte file I have a 1.1 Gbyte folder. From this folder I removed about the half (all the x64 stuff I don't care) and repack it with 7-zip ultra compression rate. At the end I had a 110 Mbyte compressed file!

Now to my question: how does MS compress their installation packages with a so high compression rate?

Comment: Why is microsoft not providing different standalone packages for 32 & 62 bit versions??? :-/

Comment: As a completely unfounded guess, I can imagine its a lot easier for Microsoft to support a package that just works... irrespective of whether its 32 or 64 bit. Contemporary hardware means drive space, cpu and networking are considered to be dealing with the unused portion of the install without any significant issue.